# Fetch editors name in google spreadsheet and write it to cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, acl

Is there any way to have an onEdit function that fetches **the editors name** and writes it to B2 whenever A2 is changed?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hYp2KAZSlRN2HNUWvyHAkc35mJtDPBSVipl4PtrSIJw/edit?usp=sharing

(e.g, the name of my google account is "Thomas G.", so this should be written to B2.)
Possible?

Answer (score 1):

**IMPORTANT CAVEAT:** the code below will generally work only if the owner/publisher of the script and the user accessing the sheet belong to the **same Google Apps domain**. It will NOT work for non-apps users.

You can do this with the following onEdit() method in your sheet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var editedRange = e.range;
  if ( editedRange.getColumn()==1 ) { // if column A was edited
    var u = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    editedRange.offset(0, 1).setValue(u); // write user's email to corresponding row in column B
  }
};
```

Note: this will require users to authorize the script's access to their data on Google (to know the user's email).

Comment: Just tried this in my linked document, nothing happens though... did it work for you? Also, I would like to receive the Name, not the email, if thats possible...

Comment: @TobiasH I have edited my answer since, apparently, e.user is not populated by default and DOES NOT trigger proper authorization from user. Change the code to use Session service instead. Did you use the updated code?

Comment: Hmmm Further testing shows it still does not trigger proper authorization from non-owner account. Let me tinker with it a bit more...

Comment: Yes, i neded to Run it from the Script first, then it was asking me to authorize, and then it worked. However, this is not too practical in my case. I wanted to embed that piece of the spreadsheet in a website, and give specific users the Link to that spreadsheet to update the status. Now, I would need to tell everyone to first open the script editor, run the script and then authorize. Is there any way to at least let them authorize without going to the script editor? UPDATE: JINX! great, thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to achieve now - so users are automatically asked to authorize when they open the sheet. Simple triggers (onOpen(), onEdit()) do not trigger this by default. Looking for a work-around...

Comment: IMPORTANT CAVEAT: the code in the answer will generally work if the owner/publisher of the script and the user accessing the sheet belong to the same Google Apps domain. It will NOT work for non-apps users. Answer updated to include the above caveat.