# Extract Cell Editor Name and Write it to Corresponding Row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

Similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091149/fetch-editors-name-in-google-spreadsheet-and-write-it-to-cell), I have a specific usecase,

I have a spreadsheet(GSheets) that contains 600 rows in column A, my work is to right click on each cell and identify the person who last edited that cell and paste his/her name to the adjacent row in column B.

Can someone help a workaround to automate this task using AppScripts?

Comment: Do you identify the person through "Show Edit history"? This is a new feature that is not implemented in Apps Script yet. But the solution of the question linked by you will directly insert the name of the editor into column B each time a cell in column A is edited, so you do not need to do it posteriorly.

Comment: 1. thats correct, i need to do that 'show edit history'. 
2. yea but in case i already have the text in the column A, so what I need the App script to do it. Identify the person with who has done it. the script in the link will result the persons name if the a new edit is made but in my case i am dealing with identifying the name of the existing editor of a cell box

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!="Sheet Name")return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==1) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
  }
}
```